# I am new to Flutter and working in audio player app. and i use On_audio_player and Just_audio package in this app

Tags: flutter

I get the list of songs from the file and the song is played. But the next and previous buttons are not working.I also use .seekToNext and .hasNext function,but not work this function..

any suggestion that how can i handle this problem.

Comment: Please provide your code and any error messages you're getting, so we can analyze what you're doing.